# Can all games still be played when switching from 32-bit to 64-bit Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, system-requirements

Right now I'm using 32-bit Windows 10. I heard you can keep all personal files when re-installing Windows 10. I have two partitions.

- `C:/` drive with the Windows installation.
- `D:/` drive with all my games installed to it

I've already made backups for all my saves.

If I re-install 64-bit Windows 10, **Can I still play all my games?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about software (does not necessarily apply to games). | Try asking on [su] perhaps?

Comment: but i`m asking about game spesifically . .

Comment: Since OP is only asking about games, this should be on topic. The fact that the same answer applies to software is a moot point. So does a lot of questions posted on here, including system requirement queries, which has its own tag.

Comment: If OP was asking "could this particular title work if I upgrade to 64 bit" it appears we would accept it. If five more popped up, we would accept them, too. Eventually, someone would get annoyed, and create a single question to direct all questions. That is exactly what this question already provides.

Comment: @Timelord64 Just because it's about games, doesn't mean it's on-topic. It's just like the font identification; just because there's a font like Willowbody in Borderlands 2, it doesn't mean that it's our expertice to work out that it's in the game (from before we know that) from a single picture. | Remember: We play games, not identify fonts, or for the most part: are experts in Information Technology and the Windows(R) operating system.

Comment: @aytimothy, your comparing something as simple as "will my game break if i upgrade from 32 to 64" to a question asking specifically about the font face used in a game. I would be more inclined to say "what font do they use" would come down to developer intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, your games 32-bit should be compatible with 64-bit systems, only that some restrictions exist, such as:

- Have a maximum (2GB) RAM allocation.
- Very small performance drop (compared to their 64-bit counterparts, but should be unnoticeable).

---

As for the "keep all my personal files and apps upon reinstall" bit, it will preserve your inner system information, such as the registry and user information, almost like an upgrade.

The "keep all my personal files upon reinstall" will however, not preserve your inner system information and instead just create an [unusable] copy of your old system in `C:\Windows.old\...` and then install a fresh copy of Windows, which is like installing a new operating system (only that it keeps the old files; automatic backup)

See [this SuperUser question for more information](https://superuser.com/questions/923162/update-to-windows-10-what-is-going-to-happen-to-my-data-and-apps).

Comment: but i thought 32-bit registry is different from 64-bit registry.

Comment: I'm not sure if have 32-bit-to-64-bit support, since I never really sat down to find out the inner workings, only to leave the upgrade to happen silently. (But I did upgrade a 32-bit Windows 7 to 64-bit Windows 10 and it went smoothly)

Comment: @NamikazeSheena. The 32 bit and 64 bit registries are indeed different, but the 32 bit registry exists within the 64 bit registry at the following path: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`. 64 bit apps can access the 32 bit registry if they have permission and know where to look, but 32 bit apps can't access the 64 bit registry.

Comment: `will preserve your inner system information ... will not preserve your inner system information`. I think you may have intended to type outer one of those times.

Comment: @nukeforum There's two types "file preserving" installations. The top one is for system upgrades, where all your old settings and everything is preserved when moving to a new OS, while the bottom one is (quite literally) copy-pasting your entire C Drive, placing it in a separate folder and then install a fresh copy of Windows.

Comment: @aytimothy I misdiff'd the two sentences. Sorry for the confusion. I know the difference. I think Win10 does 32->64bit upgrades in place now though.